# PHPExcel - Saving weird Characters to Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel version 1.8.0, 2014-03-02.

In the Excel I have this kind of cells:
Ahumada nº 301 / Huérfanos

But in the database shows:
Ahumada nÂº 301 / HuÃ©rfanos

Any one knows how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = 'data.xlsx'; 

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);

for($i=2;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    $local      =   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]['A']);
    $descripcion=   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]['B']);
    $comuna     =   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]['C']);
    $region     =   trim($allDataInSheet[$i]['D']);
    $insertTable= "INSERT INTO sucursales (Numero, Direccion, Comuna, Region, ID_Cliente) VALUES('".$local."', '".$descripcion."','".$comuna."', '".$region."', '".$_POST['select_cliente2']."');";
    mysqli_query($con,$insertTable);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: PHPExcel works with UTF-8 data.... make sure your database connection is UTF-8, and that your tables are set for UTF-8 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8")
```

In the connection to mysql and now is working as it should be!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way! I just add this line in the php and everything worked!

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: FYI that does not actually effect what the db is storing

Comment: That's true! How can I change that? Thanks.